# Stratified concordance index (survival::survConcordance)

Tags: r, survival, cox-model, confounding, concordance

What is the idea of having a stratified concordance (C-index) in survival::survConcordance, as opposed to computing the concordance over all samples ignoring the strata?

Can there be some inflation of the C-index if the strata themselves are predictive of time to outcome? (some sort of confounding)

[edit: to clarify, the non-stratified index computes the ranking of all pairs of individuals regardless of sex, the stratified index only compares males to males and females to females and then combines the estimates]

Here's some example code based on rms::rcorr.cens example where survival time is driven by age in males but not in females, which shows a big difference in the C-index between computing it on all samples versus computing it within strata (sex) and then combining into one estimate:

```
library(survival)

set.seed(123)
n <- 400
age <- rnorm(n, 50, 20)
sex <- sample(c("M", "F"), length(age), replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.7, 0.3))
d.time <- rexp(length(age), ifelse(sex == "M", age, 1)) * 1e2
cens   <- runif(length(age), 15, 30)
death  <- d.time <= cens
d.time <- pmin(d.time, cens)
d <- data.frame(age=age, time=d.time, sex=sex, death=death)

s1 <- with(d, survConcordance(Surv(time, death) ~ age))
s2 <- with(d, survConcordance(Surv(time, death) ~ age + strata(sex)))

> s1
Call:
survConcordance(formula = Surv(time, death) ~ age)

  n= 400 
Concordance= 0.5420224 se= 0.01769964
concordant discordant  tied.risk  tied.time   std(c-d) 
 40572.000  34281.000      0.000      0.000   2649.742 
> s2
Call:
survConcordance(formula = Surv(time, death) ~ age + strata(sex))

  n= 400 
Concordance= 0.6121132 se= 0.02236015
      concordant discordant tied.risk tied.time  std(c-d)
sex=F       1058       1297         0         0  290.0925
sex=M      24461      14874         0         0 1574.2970
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the `strata` argument was designed for use with certain stratified models, that only try to compare data points within each stratum, rather than between the strata. An example would be [stratified Cox proportional hazards models](http://stat.ethz.ch/education/semesters/ss2011/seminar/contents/presentation_5.pdf).

These models are like ordinary Cox proportional hazards models, but they relax the assumptions by allowing a different baseline hazard function in each stratum. Effectively, these models allow the hazard functions not to be proportional between instances in two different strata (but they must still be proportional *within* each stratum).

The problem is that the proportional hazards model doesn't actually find the baseline hazard: it gives you a model $h(t) = \lambda_0(t) e^{-X\beta}$, but it doesn't find what $\lambda_0$ is. This is OK with an un-stratified model, since you rank instances purely by the $e^{-X\beta}$ component. However, if you stratify, then you have a different $\lambda_0$ for each stratum, and hence the $e^{-X\beta}$ components are not directly comparable between strata. But you can still take them and feed them directly into `survConcordance` with the appropriate strata.

The interpretation of what you're seeing in this case doesn't have much to do with that, though. You're basically computing the rank correlation between `age` and survival (Harrell's *c* and Kendall's tau are closely related), and the stratification just controls for sex. So, as you mentioned in the post, it's basically confounding: you've discovered that age explains more of the variance in survival within each sex than when you pool the sexes. That said, most models should take this into account, so I would guess that if you created a good survival model that included both `age` and `sex`, you wouldn't see a big difference in the concordance index depending on whether or not you stratified.